# Geany search and replace in few keystrokes

Tags: regex, search, replace, geany

I'm looking for a quick way to search and replace in Geany, particularly using regex. I can select a word and do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to bring up the dialog, then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> and type in the replacement. But then I need to hoist the mouse up to the "InDocument" button.

Is there a way to do that with a keystroke? Web search did not turn up anything yet.

Also, is there a way I can do a quick regex search or search and replace?

Answer (score 2):

When the **Replace** modal window is open, use the following keyboard shortcuts:

- <kbd>Alt+o</kbd> for "In Session"
- <kbd>Alt+i</kbd> for "In Document"
- <kbd>Alt+n</kbd> for "In Selection"

[image]